# How to understand connected USB port type from the UFP side?

Tags: usb, current-limiting, usb-device

I am designing a USB 3.X device with a Type-C receptacle. I know that a standard USB 3.X downstream port can supply 900mA current and a USB 2.0 port can supply 500mA current. I am expecting the designed board to draw a current between 500mA-900mA and this would cause a problem if a user connects it to the PC's USB2.0 port. I am looking for a way to understand the type of DFP and warn the user to use an external supply or connect it to a USB3.0 port. I will use the FT601 chip as a USB3.0 bridge and it can only tell whether the connected port is standard(500mA/900mA) or charging(1.5A) port, but doesn't tell if it is 500mA or 900mA. Do you have any design suggestions to understand the port type?

Comment: Do you plan to use USB3 communication?

Comment: Yes, we are going to use USB3 communication. It turned out that FT601 can tell PC through API calls whether the connected port is USB2 or USB3. We also have a separate USB2 communication port and will send this info to MCU through that interface.